# How to fix "type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete" in C

Tags: c

Here's my code. I'm getting error:

> type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete

at the line where function minCost is called inside `main()`. Please help!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int minCost(int cost[][], int m, int n)
{
if (n < 0 || m < 0)
   return INT_MAX;
else if (m == 0 && n == 0)
  return cost[m][n];
else
  return cost[m][n] + min(minCost(cost, m-1, n),minCost(cost, m, n-1) );
}

int min(int y, int z)
{
   if (y < z)
      return y;
   else
      return z;
}

int main()
{
    int test_case,m,n,pos_m,pos_n;
    int cost[20][20];
    scanf("%d",test_case);
    scanf("%d%d",m,n);
    scanf("%d%d",pos_m,pos_n);

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            scanf("%d",cost[i][j]);
    printf("%d",minCost(cost, pos_m, pos_n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh `int cost[20][]` --> `int cost[][20]` typo ?

Comment: `scanf("%d",test_case);` --> `scanf("%d", &test_case);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY baah....sure...guess it's already been a long day for me...00:30 AM here...thanks.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output several warning messages, along with the error message about the function parameter.  Those warning messages should not be ignored, rather they should be corrected.  For instance, this statement: `scanf("%d",test_case);` raises a warning,  That MUST be fixed.  The `scanf is expecting the address of parameters, not the parameter it self (note special case for arrays degrading into the address)  So the statement should be: `scanf( "%d", &test_case );` (added horizontal spacing for readability) (cont)

Comment: (cont) with out the 'address of' operator, `scanf()` will use the current contents of `test_case` as if it were an address and that is where the input value will be placed.  That 'address' could be anywhere in memory, is undefined behavior, and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. (use the '{}' button to get the code auto formated)  3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 4) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent).

Comment: Variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  variable names like: 'm', 'n', 'z', 'y' are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: for readability (the compiler does not care) insert a space inside parens, after commas, after internal semicolons, inside brackets,

Comment: regarding: `return cost[m][n] + min(minCost(cost, m-1, n),minCost(cost, m, n-1) );`.   1) is contains a forward reference to the function: `min()` without a corresponding prototype for that function.  2) the last parameter calls the enclosing function, making it a recursive function, without any guarantee that the recursion will ever end.

Comment: the posted code is expecting the user to enter 5 different items, then a string of 'cost' items without prompting the user as to what the user is expected to input.  I.E. the user will be looking at a blank terminal window, with a blinking cursor and no idea of that to do next.   This 'lack of prompts' is only acceptable when a 'file' is feeding `stdin', such as when doing a problem for 'codechef' or similar.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this statement: `int main()` is telling the compiler that the `main()` function can have any number of any types of parameters.  This causes the compiler to produce less that correct code.  Strongly suggest using the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. (20, 20)  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Answer (score 6):

when passing a parameter, such as in this statement:

```
int minCost(int cost[][], int m, int n)
```

The 'cost[][]' second index must contain the number of elements.  otherwise the compiler does not know how much to change the offset when the first index is incremented/decremented.   Suggest:

```
int minCost(int cost[][20], int m, int n)
```

Answer (score 4):

The recommended syntax for functions with 2D array parameters is

```
int minCost(size_t m, size_t n, int cost[m][n]);
```

thereby you don't have to leave any of the dimensions incomplete. (And `m` and `n` must come before `cost` in the list.)

This will not work for your function though, because for one of your recursive call you try to reduce the number of columns of the matrix. There is no compiler magic that would do that.

Comment: I think the function parameters `m` and `n` are indices into the array,  not its dimensions. (Which is poor, since `main` used the same variable names for the dimensions)